# storing data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to store the following incoming data into the DB, and it is successfully stored except one thing.

As I type : `$request->user()->posts()->save($answer);`   , everything is saved fine except the `post_id`. 
And if I replace it with : `$post->answers()->save($answer);`  , everything is saved fine except the `user_id`.
How do I edit the save() method to save both ?

Code from the controller :

```
public function postAnswer(Request $request, $post_id)
    {


        $post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();
        $body = $request['body'];
        $pros = $request['pros'];
        $cons = $request['cons'];

        $answer = new Answer();
        $answer->body = $body;
        $answer->pros = $pros;
        $answer->cons = $cons;


 $post->answers()->save($answer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to save two relationships at one time. AFAIK, that won't work.

You'll need to save the post to the user first, then save the answer to the post.

```
$request->user()->posts()->save($post);
$post->answers()->save($answer);
```

**UPDATE**

OP needs the `user_id` saved within the `answers` table, so we need to save that relationship as well. With the two lines of code above, `$answer` doesn't know anything about the user, just the parent `$post` -- so we have to explicitly tell `$answer` that it belongs to the `user`:

```
$request->user()->answers()->save($answer);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but again only the post_id is stored in the DB.

Comment: where does the `user_id` need to be saved? Does the `$answer` need the `user_id`?  If so, then you need to save that relation too:  `$request->user()->answers()->save($answer);`

Comment: That worked ... Thanks. But I'd like to mention that putting both will also work , as follows:       $request->user()->answers()->save($answer);
                                 $post->answers()->save($answer);

Comment: Well, yes, that's the idea. Your `answer` table has a `post_id` field and a `user_id` field. You need to save both relationships to fill both fields.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add this to your models:

**Post.php:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'post_id',
    ...
];
```

Or the necessary fields, good luck.